# How to linearize a piecewise objective function into a single linear program

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization

The Question:

In a certain **nonlinear** programming problem, the objective is to maximize the function 
$$f(x_1) + 2x_2 - 5x_3,$$
where 
$$f(x_1) = \begin{cases}
2x_1 + 1 & \text{if } 0 \leq x_1 < 1 \\
x_1 + 2 & \text{if } 1 \leq x_1 < 2 \\
-2x_1 + 8 & \text{if } 2 \leq x_1
\end{cases}$$
subject to some linear constraint involving $x_1,x_2,$ and $x_3$ and nonnegativity restrictions on $x_1,x_2$, and $x_3$.

a. Describe how to linearize the objective function so that the problem may be solved via a single linear program. **Hint:** Graph $y = 2x_1 + 1$, $y= x_1 + 2$, and $y= -2x_1 + 8$, and $y = f(x_1)$ for $0 \leq x_1 \leq 3$. How does the graph of $y=f(x_1)$ relate to the graphs of $y = 2x_1 + 1$, $y= x_1 + 2$, and $y= -2x_1 + 8$?

b. Now suppose that

$$f(x_1) = \begin{cases}
-x_1 + 4 & \text{if } 0 \leq x_1 < 1 \\
x_1 + 2 & \text{if } 1 \leq x_1 < 2 \\
-2x_1 + 8 & \text{if } 2 \leq x_1 \\
\end{cases}$$
Would the same approach work here? Explain why or why not.

Can someone give me some ideas on how to solve this? Thank you!

Comment: Please **do not** delete questions which already have answers.

Comment: What possible reason is there to do that, by the way?

Answer (score 1):

Provided that the piecewise linear function to be maximized is continuous and concave down, we can transform it into

\begin{align}
\mbox{maximize }\,&y+2x_2-5x_3\\
\mbox{subject to }\,&y\leq 2x_1+1,\\
& y\leq x_1+2,\\
& y\leq -2x_1+8.\\
\end{align}
The variables are $x_1,x_2,x_3,y$. The nonnegative constraints are $\,x_1\geq 0, x_2\geq 0, x_3\geq 0\,$ as usual. If the piecewise function is not concave down, the maximization requires trials and errors.

For problem b, one can study two cases: $x_1\leq 1$ and $x_1\geq 1$. In the two ranges of $x_1$, the problem is concave down and has a unique maximum. Then compare the two maxima to see which one is the global maximum. The method is called branch and bound, which is useful for solving non-convex (because optimization theory often deals with minimization problems) or integer programming problems.

Comment: Thank you, this is what i was trying to get at. Now, is it assumed that there are additional constraints not specified for x_2 and x_3?

Comment: The $x_1\leq 1$ and $x_1\geq 1$ cut the problem into two. All original constraints are kept and only one constraint is added to make the two subproblems concave. In part a, the constraints are $y$ less than equal to all three functions of $x_1$ and that $x_1,x_2,x_3$ are all nonnegative. Should be no more constraints.